# Weird Python behaviour - or am I missing something

Tags: python, oop

The following code:

```
class House:
    links = []

class Link:
    pass

class Villa(House):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    house = House()
    villa = Villa()
    link = Link()
    house.links.append(link)

    print house.links
    print villa.links
```

results in this output:

```
[<__main__.Link instance at 0xb65a4b0c>] 
[<__main__.Link instance at 0xb65a4b0c>]
```

I find this very weird: Since it is another instance? - I would have expected that the output is - Since it is another instance?:

```
[<__main__.Link instance at 0xb65a4b0c>] 
[]
```

When changing the line `house.links.append(link)` to `house.links = [link]` everything works as expected.

Can somebody explain this behavior?

Answer (score 19):

It is another instance, but you have defined `links` as a class variable rather than an instance variable.

An instance variable would be defined as such:

```
class House(object):  # Always use new-style classes except for backward compatibility
  def __init__(self):
    self.links = []
```

Note that in Python, unlike other languages, an instance variable is explicitly declared to be a property of an instance.  This usually happens in the `__init__` method, to ensure that every instance has the variable.

Then, the subclass would look like this:

```
class Villa(House):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Villa, self).__init__()
```

And executing your code gives the correct results:

```
>>> house = House()
>>> villa = Villa()
>>> link = Link()
>>> house.links.append(link)
>>> print house.links
[<__main__.Link instance at 0xcbaa8>]
>>> print villa.links
[]
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `links` is an attribute on the class, making it shared by all instances of that class:

```
class House:
    links = []
```

Because of this, your `Villa` class shares this attribute, because an instance of `Villa` is (as a subclass) also an instance of `House`.

If you want to make `links` an instance variable, write a constructor and set `links` as an attribute of `self`, e.g.

```
class House:
    def __init__(self):
        self.links = []
```